# KDB: generate random string

Tags: string, random, kdb

How can one generate a random string of a given length in KDB? The string should be composed of both upper and lower case alphabet characters as well as digits, and the first character can not be a digit.

Example:

```
"i0J2Jx3qa" / OK
"30J2Jx3qa" / bad
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
stringLength: 13
randomString: (1 ? .Q.A,.Q.a) , ((stringLength-1) ? .Q.nA,.Q.a)
```

Comment: For `.Q` constants, see [the Reference](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/)

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer without the repetitions:

```
raze(1,stringLength-1)?'10 0_\:.Q.nA,.Q.a
```

Comment: I get repetitions of characters in the strings: for example, `"nlIP3JUWObbju"`, `"Oz0QlHohhoCrQ"`, `"nj8AvFAASj3qy"`... Are you saying that this method produces unique strings which never repeat?

Comment: Not at all. The repetitions were in the accepted answer: Join, `.Q.a`, and Deal.

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of creating random data you can also use `?/deal` with a number of characters up to 8 as a symbol(which you could string). This doesn't include numbers though so just an alternative approach to your own answer.

```
1?`8
,`bghgobnj
```

Comment: Also worth noting this only generates characters from a-p (does not include q-z). https://code.kx.com/q/ref/deal/#generate

Comment: Doesn’t answer OP.

Answer (score 0):

There's already a fine answer above which has been accepted. Just wanted somewhere to note that if this is to generate truly random data you need to consider randomising your seed. This can be done in Linux by using $RANDOM in bash or reading up to four bytes from /dev/random (relatively recent versions of kdb can read directly from FIFOs).

Otherwise the seed is set to digits from pi: 314159